# Javascript reduce array of objects and return distinct array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of invoice objects that I want to turn into a distinct array of just the supplier ID, supplier name and a reduced total across all the invoices from each distinct supplier where the status equals 3. Here is what I have so far:

```
const invoices = [
  {
    invoiceNumber: "12345678",
    invoiceDate: "12th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 1200,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "87654321",
    invoiceDate: "10th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 800,
    status: 1
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "13572468",
    invoiceDate: "8th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 1000,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "AB1234",
    invoiceDate: "12th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP456",
    supplierName: "Steve Systems Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 500,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "XY5678",
    invoiceDate: "4th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP456",
    supplierName: "Steve Systems Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 700,
    status: 3
  }
]
```

Here is the desired output:

```
[
  {
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoicesTotal: 2200
  },
  {
    supplierId: "SUP456",
    supplierName: "Steve Systems Ltd",
    invoicesTotal: 1200
  }
]
```

I've managed to piece together getting an array of distinct suppliers but am now stuck on how to reduce the relevant invoice totals from the original invoice array and insert that into the relevant supplier object in the arr array:

```
const distinctSupplierMap = new Map(
      invoices.map((invoice) => [invoice.supplierId, invoice])
    );
const distinctSuppliersFilter = [...distinctSupplierMap.values()];
let arr = [];
    distinctSuppliersFilter.map((distSupp) => {
      arr.push({
        supplierId: distSupp.supplierId,
        supplierName: distSupp.supplierName,
      });
    });
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please clarify if the `status: 3` filter should omit suppliers entirely or should only apply to the total summing

Comment: Hi Phil, to clarify: yes, if status === 3 for all invoices for a particular supplier then return supplierId, supplierName and invoicesTotal: 0

Comment: That's not really what I asked. Just say there's a third supplier (eg `SUP789`) in your data but all their entries have `status: 1`. Should that supplier appear in the output with `invoicesTotal: 0` or should it not appear at all

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yes, if a supplier only has entries where status: 1, they should be returned with invoicesTotal: 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want two steps

1. Reduce and sum totals by tracking `supplierId` in a map, only adding when `status === 3`
2. Extract the values from your map

```js
const invoices = [{"invoiceNumber":"12345678","invoiceDate":"12th September 2023","supplierId":"SUP123","supplierName":"Roger Enterprises Ltd","invoiceTotal":1200,"status":3},{"invoiceNumber":"87654321","invoiceDate":"10th September 2023","supplierId":"SUP123","supplierName":"Roger Enterprises Ltd","invoiceTotal":800,"status":1},{"invoiceNumber":"13572468","invoiceDate":"8th September 2023","supplierId":"SUP123","supplierName":"Roger Enterprises Ltd","invoiceTotal":1000,"status":3},{"invoiceNumber":"AB1234","invoiceDate":"12th September 2023","supplierId":"SUP456","supplierName":"Steve Systems Ltd","invoiceTotal":500,"status":3},{"invoiceNumber":"XY5678","invoiceDate":"4th September 2023","supplierId":"SUP456","supplierName":"Steve Systems Ltd","invoiceTotal":700,"status":3}];

const arr = Object.values(
  invoices.reduce(
    (map, { supplierId, supplierName, invoiceTotal, status }) => {
      map[supplierId] ??= { supplierId, supplierName, invoicesTotal: 0 };
      if (status === 3) {
        map[supplierId].invoicesTotal += invoiceTotal;
      }
      return map;
    },
    {},
  ),
);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: @Rich keeping things honest, [TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77226404/283366) was first and guessed correctly how you wanted to handle the status filter

Answer (score 2):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const invoices = [  {    invoiceNumber: '12345678',    invoiceDate: '12th September 2023',    supplierId: 'SUP123',    supplierName: 'Roger Enterprises Ltd',    invoiceTotal: 1200,    status: 3,  },  {    invoiceNumber: '87654321',    invoiceDate: '10th September 2023',    supplierId: 'SUP123',    supplierName: 'Roger Enterprises Ltd',    invoiceTotal: 800,    status: 1,  },  {    invoiceNumber: '13572468',    invoiceDate: '8th September 2023',    supplierId: 'SUP123',    supplierName: 'Roger Enterprises Ltd',    invoiceTotal: 1000,    status: 3,  },  {    invoiceNumber: 'AB1234',    invoiceDate: '12th September 2023',    supplierId: 'SUP456',    supplierName: 'Steve Systems Ltd',    invoiceTotal: 500,    status: 3,  },  {    invoiceNumber: 'XY5678',    invoiceDate: '4th September 2023',    supplierId: 'SUP456',    supplierName: 'Steve Systems Ltd',    invoiceTotal: 700,    status: 3,  },];
const o = invoices.reduce((m, c) => {
  const old = m.get(c.supplierId) ?? {
    supplierId: c.supplierId,
    supplierName: c.supplierName,
  };
  old.invoiceTotal =
    (old.invoiceTotal ?? 0) + (c.status === 3 ? c.invoiceTotal : 0);
  return m.set(c.supplierId, old);
}, new Map());
console.log([...o.values()]);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Only thing I'd want OP to clarify is if any new suppliers without `status: 3` should appear in the results with `invoicesTotal: 0` or should they be omitted entirely

Comment: Looks like you guessed right with the filter. Nice!

Comment: @Phil Your code looks much better though. Gotta iron my edges...

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `filter` to filter out the object where status is not `3` then use reduce to create a an object where the key will be the `supplierId`. At the end use `Object.values` to get an array out of the object

```js
const invoices = [{
    invoiceNumber: "12345678",
    invoiceDate: "12th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 1200,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "87654321",
    invoiceDate: "10th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 800,
    status: 1
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "13572468",
    invoiceDate: "8th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP123",
    supplierName: "Roger Enterprises Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 1000,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "AB1234",
    invoiceDate: "12th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP456",
    supplierName: "Steve Systems Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 500,
    status: 3
  },
  {
    invoiceNumber: "XY5678",
    invoiceDate: "4th September 2023",
    supplierId: "SUP456",
    supplierName: "Steve Systems Ltd",
    invoiceTotal: 700,
    status: 3
  }
].filter(curr => curr.status === 3).reduce((acc, curr) => {

  const supplierId = curr.supplierId;
  if (!acc[supplierId]) {
    acc[supplierId] = {
      supplierId: curr.supplierId,
      supplierName: curr.supplierName,
      invoicesTotal: curr.invoiceTotal
    }
  } else {
    acc[supplierId] = {
      ...acc[supplierId],
      invoicesTotal: acc[supplierId].invoicesTotal + curr.invoiceTotal,

    }

  }
  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(Object.values(invoices))
```